# How is the column height calculated in CSS3 columns

Tags: html, css

i need to create PDFs from web pages and i'm using PhantomJS to achieve this. It uses a headless Chromium browser to render the page and rasterize it to a PDF. The Chromium browser has a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=99358) regarding the printing of CSS3 columns so i've written a Javascript to mimic the behaviour (using floats).

```
-webkit-columns: 3;
-moz-columns: 3;
columns: 3;

-webkit-column-gap: 24px;
-moz-column-gap: 24px;
column-gap: 24px;
```

I was wondering if anybody knows how the CSS3 property calculates the height of the columns. When i set a height on the parent element it honors that height and overflows content that doesn't fit into an additional column.

In my project the height of an element can be unknown so i need a way to determine the height of each column. Currently i'm using the height of the original non-columned content as a max but that doesn't cover all cases.

In this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vxm1ygd8/) i've demonstrated the CSS3 behaviour, the green container has a max-height, the gray container doesn't. How is the height of the columns in the gray container calculated?

Comment: (1) The number that you specify in `columns: 3` is not a hard limit. It is only indicative. As long as 3 columns can be made out of available height and width, it will. Otherwise it will overflow and increase or decrease the columns. (2) In your first case (green), there is fixed height beyond which the content overflows and number of columns increase. (3) In your second case, (the gray one) there is no fixed height and so the browser will try its best to keep content in 3 columns as long as it can increase the height, which it does.

Comment: You're right. When i add more content to the gray container it will stretch the columns and divide the content equal. Now is just need a way to calculate the max-height of the container but that is beyond the scope of this question.